# how to perform custom operations on an array to get a specific result in ruby using map or by using some enumarator methods?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array, `late_mark_array`:

```
["yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no"]
```

These indicate an employee's consecutive "late marks" in a particular month. In this array `"yes"` indicates "late". `"no"` indicates "not late". I want to implement `penalties` for "lates".  To calculate penalties in above array:

- If there are three consecutive `"yes"` marks then I want to increment the `penalty` count by one.
- The penalty needs to be incremented by one for each consecutive `"yes"` following the initial 3.

Using this logic, the `penalty` to the above employee should be `"6"`.

I do not know how to implement this logic for the above array.

i have one more requirement where `penalties` needs to be calculated for both `consecutive late marks` and for `random late marks` too. means for example i have an array `["yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no"]`. in this at the end of the array `"yes"`, `"no"` repeated alternatively. as these three late marks at the end, are not consecutive lates. an `employee` is not getting any `penalty` for this. in this case i want `penalty` needs to be applied for both `consecutive` and for `random late marks` too. so in this case the `penalty` of an `employee` should be  "5". how can i do this?

Comment: Iterate over the array. Each time you have a "yes" increment a counter. If you get a not-"yes" before that counter reaches the max, reset it back to zero. What's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.each_cons(3)` and then count the number of slices containing all `"yes"`:

```
irb> input = ["yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no"]
=> ["yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no"]
irb> input.each_cons(3).count { |slice| slice.all? { |item| item == "yes" } }
=> 6
```

Comment: i have updated the question for other requirement can any body help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

OK, you could do something like this, using [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html) methods:

```
> arr =   ["yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no"]
=> ["yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no"]

> penalties = arr.chunk {|a| a=="yes"}.
                  map { |late, array| array.count - 2 if late }.
                  compact.
                  inject {|s,i|s+i}
=> 6
```

Comment: I'd say "shorten" before "simplify" in this case.  ;)  Nice though.  Thanks!

Comment: You could simplify to `arr.chunk { |a| a=="yes" }.inject(0) { |tot, (tf,a)| tot + (tf ? [a.size-2, 0].max : 0) } #=> 6`. (I deleted my original comment--to which chad replied--because I messed up an aside. :-)

Comment: i have updated the question for other requirement can any body help me with that?